# Jetpack Compose makes LiveData observer returns a wrong data type: foo.Bar cannot be cast to kotlin.Result

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack-compose

When the Jetpack Compose flag is not enabled in the app's gradle `build.gradle.kts` file, my LiveData observer returns the correct data type `kotlin.Result<List<Person>>` for `personsResult` as per my code in the Fragment:

```
private fun observePersons() {
        val observer: (kotlin.Result<List<Person>>) -> Unit = { personsResult ->
            // Do something
        }
        viewModel.personsResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
    }
```

However, when I enable it :

```
buildFeatures{
        compose = true
    }
```

the LiveData observer returns a `personsResult` of the type `ArrayList<Person>` instead of `kotlin.Result<List<Person>>`, resulting in the app crashing with the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to kotlin.Result
```

When I look at the stacktrace, it seems that the `mData` in the LiveData is still the correct type up until `onChanged()` is called :

```
invoke:61, DevPersonListFragment$observePersons$observer$1  // personsResult as? kotlin.Result<List<Person>> == null
invoke:60, DevPersonListFragment$observePersons$observer$1 
onChanged:-1, DevPersonListFragment$sam$androidx_lifecycle_Observer$0 
considerNotify:133, LiveData (androidx.lifecycle)           // mData as? kotlin.Result<List<Person>> != null
dispatchingValue:151, LiveData (androidx.lifecycle)
setValue:309, LiveData (androidx.lifecycle)
setValue:50, MutableLiveData (androidx.lifecycle)
invokeSuspend:99, LiveDataScopeImpl$emit$2 (androidx.lifecycle)
resumeWith:33, BaseContinuationImpl (kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal)
run:106, DispatchedTask (kotlinx.coroutines)
handleCallback:938, Handler (android.os)
dispatchMessage:99, Handler (android.os)
loop:223, Looper (android.os)
main:7656, ActivityThread (android.app)
run:592, RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:947, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

My Lifecycle dependencies are the following

```
implementation(Libs.Lifecycle.viewmodelCompose)
implementation(Libs.Lifecycle.Ktx.viewmodel)
implementation(Libs.Lifecycle.Ktx.runtime)
implementation(Libs.Lifecycle.Ktx.livedata)
```

.

```
object Lifecycle {
            const val viewmodelCompose = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha04"
            object Ktx {
                private const val version = "2.3.1"
                const val livedata = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$version"
                const val runtime = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$version"
                const val viewmodel = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$version"
            }
        }
```

Edit: Here is my ViewModel

```
class PersonListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _personsResult: LiveData<kotlin.Result<List<Person>>> =
        Repository
            .getPersons()
            .asLiveData(Dispatchers.IO) as MutableLiveData

    val personsResult: LiveData<kotlin.Result<List<Person>>> = _personsResult
}
```

Repository.getPersons() has the following signature

```
fun getPersons(): Flow<kotlin.Result<List<Person>>>
```

Comment: could u share the `viewmodel` class ?

Comment: Sure, just added it

Comment: r u sure u have imported the correct result in `fun getPersons(): Flow<Result<List<Person>>>` just cross check the imports in the repository class and view model class, because `kotlin.Result` is from the kotlin package

Comment: There are no explicit imports related to Result in the ViewModel, as it is part of the kotlin package is a default import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually lies with kotlin.Result, as when the content of kotlin.Result is copied into a new class and used, it works fine.

It is similar to the bug described in this [Jetbrains issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27105). Normally it would have been possible to use kotlin.Result as a return type using the flag `-Xallow-result-return-type`, but with Jetpack Compose it doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

While waiting for them to fix this, using a copy of kotlin.Result would work.